# PHP IF something AND something THEN something?

Tags: php, if-statement

If the promotion code is "MAG20" and the product code is "99" or the product code is "77" or the product code is "44".. then do something.

(the promotion code is the same and the product list is the same too but it is large)

```
if ($promocode=="MAG20" && $productID=="44"  && || $productID=="77") {

// wahay! run function

} else {

// no coupon for you

}
```

I was hoping that IF PROMO MAG20 AND CODE IS 99 OR CODE IS 77 would work && || - also is there a better way of doing this as the bracket is going to be big, 30+ products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make an array out of all your names

```
$productIDs = array(10, 20, 30);
```

then the if function

```
if($promocode== "MAG20" && in_array($productID, $productIDs))
```

So you have 1 list of ID's, and a short if statement

Comment: I think this serves best considering speed and the lack of mySQL support.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having too many products then its better to have a sql table with products and their corresponding coupon codes. That would be a much much better and cleaner way of doing it. Having 30 conditions on a single conditional statement not only slows down your app but also is very very hard to manage.

So you can have a coupons table and a products table and a coupons_to_products table and check the final table to know if the coupon is really valid.

Comment: I appreciate your response and I agree - BUT no mysql access

Answer (score 1):

Use array if valid product IDs will change or if they are many

```
$validProductIDs = array(44, 77, 104, 204); //Up to you how you populate this array
if ($promocode == "MAG20" && in_array($productID, $validProductIDs)) {
    // wahay! run function
} else {
    // no coupon for you
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if ($promocode=="MAG20" and ($productID=="44"  or $productID=="77"))
  // wahay! run function
} else {
  // no coupon for you
}
```

Comment: @BoltClock is anything wrong with that? or you just prefer the old fashion && || ? have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
if ($promocode=="MAG20" && ($productID=="44" || $productID=="77"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [array](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) data type. Depending on your array design, you can use [isset()](http://php.net/isset), /[array_key_exists()](http://es2.php.net/array_key_exists) or [in_array()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to do the check.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why think that consecutive `&& ||` should work. What should be the meaning of this?

Anyway, what you want is:

```
$promocode=="MAG20" && ($productID=="44" || $productID=="77")
```

You have to group `$productID=="44" || $productID=="77"`, otherwise, as the AND has a higher precedence, it would be evaluated as

```
($promocode=="MAG20" && $productID=="44") || $productID=="77"
```

---

If you have to test for a lot of IDs, I suggest to use some kind of a lookup table:

```
$productIDs = array('44', '77', ...);
$productIDs = array_flip($productIDs);

if($promocode=="MAG20" && isset($productIDs[$productID])) {

}
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, otherwise I cannot improve my answer. Thank you!

Comment: may be because of oversophisticated version of in_array()?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Depends, I prefer `O(1)` access instead of linear search... granted, if you only have to do this once in the script, then you don't gain anything.

Comment: yeah and I think it doesn't deserve a downvote though. just a guess